# xaml code not working - c#

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0

I have following code:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type abc}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox Margin="0,0,3,0" x:Name="CheckBox">
                        <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                            <Binding Path="IsSelected"
                                     Mode="TwoWay">
                                <Binding.RelativeSource>
                                    <RelativeSource Mode="Template" />
                                </Binding.RelativeSource>
                            </Binding>
                        </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                    </CheckBox>                                    
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                               Margin="0,0,10,5" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Channel}"
                               Margin="7,0,0,0"
                               Visibility="{Binding Path=IsChannelVisible,ElementName=View, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibile}}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Valid}" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="CheckBox" Property="Foreground" Value="#000000"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Valid}" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="CheckBox" Property="Foreground" Value="#999999"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

What i am trying to achieve is change the color of the the checkbox text. But above code is not working. Can anyone please help me with this?

Tried code from Tilak:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="Template"
                             TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox Margin="7,0,0,0" Foreground={Binding Valid, Converter={StaticResource ValidToColorConverter}} 
                              x:Name="CheckBox">
                        <CheckBox.IsChecked>
                            <Binding Path="IsSelected"
                                     Mode="TwoWay">
                                <Binding.RelativeSource>
                                    <RelativeSource Mode="Parent" />
                                </Binding.RelativeSource>
                            </Binding>
                        </CheckBox.IsChecked>
                    </CheckBox>                    
                    <ContentPresenter />
                    <DataTemplate.CheckBox>
                        <Intellivu:ValidToColorConverter x:Key="ValidToColorConverter" />
                    </DataTemplate.CheckBox>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

This is not working? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: did you try to change Foreground property of CheckBox directly?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt - How can i change it directly? Can i do it in code some how?

Comment: <CheckBox Foreground="Red" />

Comment: @ArsenMkrt - But how does it work in code? I make it Red but in code i want to change it into grey how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use converter and bind to Foreground property directly.

Following following steps for it

Create ValidToColorConverter

```
public class ValidToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    // This converts the DateTime object to the string to display.
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
      bool valid = value as bool;
      return valid ? Colors.Black : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.FromArgb(255,99,99,99));
    }

    // No need to implement converting back on a one-way binding 
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, 
        object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Add ValidToColorConverter as static resource in the resources corresponding to control

```
 <DataTemplate.Resources>
  <local:ValidToColorConverter x:Key="ValidToColorConverter" />
</DataTemplate.Resources>
```

Note - local should be added into page namespaces(corresponding to namespace where converter is defined)

Refer to Converter in the Checkbox

```
<CheckBox Margin="0,0,3,0" Foreground={Binding Valid, Converter={StaticResource ValidToColorConverter}} x:Name="CheckBox">
```

Comment: i added how i am writing the code above. I think one error was i needed "" in Foreground value. Other errors are not recognizing ValidToColorConverter.

Comment: not recognizing ValidToColorConverter, you need to add namespace into the xaml with the name local. Something like    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ConverterParameterEx"

Comment: i am using namespace. But i am using StackPanel.Resources instead of DataTemplete.Resources. As if i use DataTemplete.Resources it gives an error: Ambiguous reference.

Comment: DateTemplate.Resources not needed. you can define it in the UserControl.Resources if it is under UserControl, or in App.Resources in App.xaml

Comment: it gives same error if i use UserControl. And if i use StackPanel.Resources it is not recoginizing ValidToColorConverter.

Comment: I think i got it to work. One last question. So in the code i need to set ValidToColorConverter = true/false for it to work right?